# Remove the ability to import previous imported file

Tags: feeds

I'm guessing someone must have done this before but I can't find a module for it.

In Feeds the last file you imported can be seen by name on the left hand side.  Next to the 'Browse' box.

If the user doesn't browse for a file then the File shown in that box is imported when clicking on the 'submit' button.  What I'd like to do is to leave this file being shown as the last import but I don't want it to be imported if no file has been selected.

Has anyone done this or something similar .

Comment: Hi Deejay,I'm free now and can help you. do you want prevent(face user with error that you are not browsed file) or nothing happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simplely remove it by using `hook_form_alter`

**don't forget replace  form_id and yourmodulename with yours  in following code**

```
function yourmodulename_form_alter(&$form,$form_state,$form_id){
    if($form_id=='feeds_import_form' ){
    unset($form['feeds']["FeedsFileFetcher"]['upload']['#file_info']);
}
}
```

**update**
in this section we prevent user to resubmit the old file,this mean if user push import button without browsed new file we prevent him to remport

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form,$form_state,$form_id){
    if($form_id=='feeds_import_form' ){
      $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_prevent_import_validate';    
}
}

function mymodule_prevent_import_validate($form,$form_state){
    if(!isset($form_state['values']['feeds']["FeedsFileFetcher"]['file'])){
            form_set_error('upload', t('Not new file uploaded'));
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Zhilevan

Thanks for this .  

However this get's rid of the File name from view but when clicking on import the file still imports.  I kind of want the opposite - I'd like to still be able to see the filename of the last upload but when clicking on Import for it to not import, that should only come from if a file has been browsed for.

Comment: @Deejay So you should handle it custom submit handler, add  ( array_unshift ) your custom submit(or validator) handler, in custom submit(validate)handler if not data posted do nothing(or return form error to fill it ) .
I'am sure the the solution for this is simple.

Comment: @Deejay I update my question .take a look at second part